# Inserting points (pixels) between elements of NSString in a UILabel

Tags: nsstring, uilabel, core-graphics, nsattributedstring

I am designing a UILabel. Its Text is an NSString that is made up of 3 different variables such as:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %@    %@", string1, string2, string 3];
```

What is the best way to separate string1, string2 and string 3 in term of points and not character spaces?

Comment: Not an option right now because of all kind of fun layout constraints in the view.

Comment: I'd guess that in overriding `drawRect:` (or something like that) you could do it, detecting each "space" and having the whole frame size and the size of each word drawn.